# How Can I Connect Java to MQL5 (Preferably Using ZeroMQ)

Tags: java, zeromq, mql4, mql5, metatrader5

Would anyone know how to do the bi-directional connection between `Java` and `MQL5`? Preferably using `ZeroMQ`.

In that case Java would receive data (probably arrays) from `MQL5`, it will compute and return information to `MQL5`. This all at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of helloworld from MQL client (it is possible to use MQL as server but it is rather difficult to imagine why someone may need that) at [github](https://github.com/dingmaotu/mql-zmq/blob/master/Scripts/ZeroMQGuideExamples/Chapter1/HelloWorldClient.mq4). Java server example is at the official page.
You may use json to exchange messages ([ydrol](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/11134) or [sergeev](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/13663) lib is to help you, keep in mind the latter may have issues with parsing arrays) or choose some other format.

Probably the easiest is to pass ticks or m1 candles to java using json, then receive trading commands to MQL.